# How does the arrival of HTML5 and CSS3 affect jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

About a year ago I picked up my first HTML book (XHTML). I have since built two simple websites with XHTML and CSS. I have also studied the basics of JavaScript.

I now want to learn jQuery.

I am not sure how, if at all, HTML5 and CSS3 make some parts of jQuery redundant - does it?

According to the reviews the best book on jQuery seems to be ‘jQuery in Action’, published 2007.

Do I need to proceed with caution when approaching jQuery, given HTML5 and CSS3? Can someone advise me?

Comment: jQuery is an API. Once you understand the basic concepts (find a tutorial online), all you have to do is read the jQuery documentation (available [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)) in order to use it. jQuery is easy, it's the language behind it (JavaScript) that you should spend time learning.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662562/does-html5-mean-doing-less-with-javascript/3663742#3663742

Comment: You don't need jQuery. jQuery is just one of tens of reliable cross browser scripting languages. You should either pick it because it popular or pick a better one

Comment: I think jQuery is better described as a framework rather than an API.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009121/learning-html5-css3-do-i-need-javascript-too

Comment: @Raynos: Ahem. http://favstar.fm/users/BoltClock/status/63609746057465856

Comment: @BoltClock did I really make a typo and used the word language rather then library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, learning jQuery is still fine and what you learn will continue to work.  While many things are possible using CSS3 that jQuery may have been required for before, many still required javascript and others are not implemented in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you can't learn all 3 at the same time.  jQuery is fairly easy to get a grasp on for the simple stuff.  I recommend the jQuery Cookbook by o'reilly.  HTML5 is still changing, but you can play with it now in most modern browsers.  The latest versions of jQuery also take these changes into account, so your learning basic jQuery does not become obsolete.

The areas to beware are using the more obscure jQuery plugins, which may not have been tested as thoroughly on all browsers or kept up to date with html5 changes.

Whenever possible I try to use HTML5 and CSS3 if the feature is well supported on the 4 major browsers and seems stable.  Otherwise I fall back to jQuery to implement the feature I need.

Answer (score 1):

[Not at all](http://www.queness.com/post/1946/10-brilliant-css3-and-jquery-examples). JQuery is compatible with CSS3, as is said within the example given. I'm sure JQuery will be around for a long time - the only thing which I see that may be a competitor in the future is [Dart](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/10/dart-googles-programming-language-for.html), or a Microsoft knock off of either Dart or JQuery.

What might be a good idea, however is to go beyond the basics of JavaScript *first* and then move on to JQuery. <strike>JQuery, while like JavaScript, is quite different syntactically, though it *is* based off of JavaScript; learning it would only make learning JQuery easier.</strike>

**Edit**

Found out that JQuery's syntax is the same as that of JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery isn’t “like” or “based off of” JavaScript, it’s a JavaScript framework.

Comment: jQuery and JavaScript do not have different syntax: _everything_ you do with jQuery is standard, valid JavaScript syntax. jQuery is a library written in JavaScript, not a distinct language.